# How to use Boost.Filesystem on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, compilation, g++

I've written a simple code which create folder. The problem is that I can't compile it. The code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
int main()
{
  boost::filesystem::create_directories("/tmp");
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
g++ createFolder.cpp -std=c++0x -lboost_system -o createFolder
```

I have got errors:

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to correct the compilation process to run this program.

Comment: It would be tremendously helpful if you could paste the whole error message, not only the last line. On my system it is: /tmp/ccXo55RP.o: In function `boost::filesystem::create_directories(boost::filesystem::path const&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem18create_directoriesERKNS0_4pathE[_ZN5boost10filesystem18create_directoriesERKNS0_4pathE]+0x19): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directories(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 6):

Try adding boost-filesystem to you linker:

```
g++ createFolder.cpp -std=c++0x -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -o createFolder
```